# EditableGrid - get new value of <td> via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, editablegrid

I am using [editableGrid](http://www.editablegrid.net/) table, and I need to copy edited content of `<td>` elements into hidden `<input>`s.

I'm trying to get those via jQuery `.text()` method, but it returns values before change. When I edit a `<td>` again, it returns previously entered text etc.
Simple example:

```
<table id="htmlgrid" class="testgrid">
<tr id="0">
    <td>Fridge 123</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="[0][name]" value="Fridge 123">
    <td>7.000 CZK</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="[0][price]" value="7000">
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, what I want to do, is change a name "Fridge 123" to "Fridge 456" and copy this new name into input:`<input type="hidden" name="[0][name]" value="Fridge 456">`

Using this jQuery code

```
$("#htmlgrid td").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

I get a value of `Fridge 123`, which is wrong. How can this be done, to get newly-entered values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [query documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/), `change` event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

Try something like

```
$("#htmlgrid td").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

or

```
$("#htmlgrid td").on("change",'input',function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```